# Remove mercurial-common from Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, mercurial, apt-get

I'm having Python 2.x problems on Ubuntu 15.04. I wanted to completely uninstall and reinstall Python. I can't uninstall Python because mercurial-common depends on it. I try to remove that and I get an error:

```
➜  ~  sudo apt-get remove --purge mercurial-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gnome-control-center-data gnome-icon-theme gnome-icon-theme-symbolic gnome-settings-daemon libcolord-gtk1 libexpat1-dev libgoa-backend-1.0-1 libjs-excanvas libpython3-dev
  libpython3.4-dev python3-colorama python3-dev python3-distlib python3-wheel python3.4-dev
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  mercurial-common*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 8,610 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 206144 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing mercurial-common (3.1.2-2+deb8u1build0.15.04.2) ...
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
ImportError: No module named site
dpkg: error processing package mercurial-common (--purge):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
ImportError: No module named site
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mercurial-common
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The mercurial-common removal scripts use python

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mercurial-common.prerm
```

If you type `which pyclean` I assume it exists.
However I suspect you python problems prevent it working. (you could try running it manually to verify this)

Unfortunately pyclean is in package python-minimal so you prolly can't uninstall this before mercurial-common.

you could try just removing it manually by:

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/pyclean /usr/bin/pyclean.backup
```

(Just remember to put it back).

Alternatively rather than completely removing python you could try just reinstalling python package .deb over the top of the existing install using `dpkg --install`